# Python, Pandas: GroupBy attributes documentation

Tags: python, pandas, jupyter-notebook

On the Groupby documentation, at that level of the page:
http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/groupby.html#groupby-object-attributes

If you scroll down a bit you can see their is a list of all the available groupby attributes:

```
gb.agg        gb.boxplot    gb.cummin     gb.describe   gb.filter     gb.get_group  gb.height     gb.last       gb.median     gb.ngroups    gb.plot       gb.rank       gb.std        gb.transform
gb.aggregate  gb.count      gb.cumprod    gb.dtype      gb.first      gb.groups     gb.hist       gb.max        gb.min        gb.nth        gb.prod       gb.resample   gb.sum        gb.var
gb.apply      gb.cummax     gb.cumsum     gb.fillna     gb.gender     gb.head       gb.indices    gb.mean       gb.name       gb.ohlc       gb.quantile   gb.size       gb.tail       gb.weight
```

Where can I find documentation about what those attributes are/do? Using the `?` in Jupyter doesn't show their docs.

Comment: I think you can check [docs](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/api.html#groupby)

Comment: I think all of them are here: http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/version/0.19.2/api.html#id35

Comment: AFAIK, you need to do this in 2 steps. First assign the grouped object to a variable, say `gb`. Then do, `gb.<attr>?` in Jupyter

Comment: Incidentally, in the docs (from where this post is taken) there's this `DF` having columns (height/weight/gender). So, I guess those get picked up as attributes.

Comment: @Radar: In Jupyter, clicking the "run cell" button after typing `gb.agg?` (for example) shows the help docstring.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you can check [groupby docs](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/api.html#groupby).

1. [Indexing, iteration](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/api.html#id34)
2. [Function application](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/api.html#function-application)
3. [Computations / Descriptive Stats](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/api.html#id35)

Answer (score 0):

Here also you can find documentation about the attributes: 
https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/groupby.html

Answer (score 0):

You can find all descriptions at this [link](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/groupby.html).
Specifically, subsections of the tab `GroupBy` in the left menu.